# Add UMLS username and password to Ctakes

Tags: java, nlp, ctakes

I'm a new user on cTAKES. I followed User Install Guide and add UMLS access rights. After I edited runctakesCPE.bat and runctakesCVD.bat, I got the following:

> F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>set CTAKES_HOME=F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0
>
> F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>if exist
>   "F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\bin\runctakesCVD.bat" goto okHome
>
> F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>if exist "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe" set PATH=C:\Program 
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\
>   jre\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Fil es\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wi
>   ndowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Fi les (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management  Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Pro gram
>   Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP Performance Advisor;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Inst aller\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windo ws Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Pr ogram Files\IDM
>   Computer Solutions\UltraEdit;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
>   2.9\miktex\bi n\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\runtime\win64;C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin;C:\Program Files\
>   IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\JRE\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
>   _65\jre\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program  Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System3
>   2\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management
>   Engine Components\DAL;C:\Progra m Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
>   Manage ment Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c: \Program
>   Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP Performance Advisor;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\W indows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C :\Program Files\IDM
>   Computer Solutions\UltraEdit;C:\Python27;C:\Users\yi
>   chen\AppData\Local\Programs \Git\cmd;C:\Users\yi
>   chen\AppData\Local\Programs\EmEditor
>
> F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>cd F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0
>
> F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>IF "" == "" GOTO NoParam
>
> F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>echo Use the GUI to select the AE to load Use
>   the GUI to select the AE to load
>
> F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>java -Dctakes.umlsuser=
>   "F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\desc\;F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\
>   resources\;F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\lib*"
>   -Dlog4j.configuration=file:\F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0\config\l og4j.xml -Xms512M -Xmx3g org.apache.uima.tools.cvd.CVD 0-cp The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> F:\apache-ctakes-4.0.0>GOTO ChangeBack

Can anyone help to figure it? I really need your help.
Thanks!

Comment: after editing the file, what command did you run? i tried the same in user install guide and it works for me

Answer (score 2):

Answering this question for sake of people who get this issue in future.

@jhshi : The changes you made in runCVD.bat do not seem correct.

**The documentation requires you to add your UMLS account username and password in every bat file (or sh file for dearest Linux users).**
Which means every cTAKES user has to create a UMLS account [here](https://uts.nlm.nih.gov//license.html).

This is done using the java cmd line arguments "-Dctakes.umlsuser" & " -Dctakes.umlspw".
Look at my java invocation line from the runCVD.bat file below.

```
java -Dctakes.umlsuser="gprakhar" -Dctakes.umlspw="XXXXXXX" -cp "%CTAKES_HOME%\desc\;%CTAKES_HOME%\resources\;%CTAKES_HOME%\lib\*" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:\%CTAKES_HOME%\config\log4j.xml -Xms512M -Xmx2g org.apache.uima.tools.cvd.CVD
```

What you did was to pass the value of some PATH like variable to the umlsuser cmd line argument.